# How to ensure access to my web service from my code only?

Tags: iphone, security, http, https

I am writing a very simple web service for my iPhone app. Let's say this is a http page that returns a random number at http://mysite/getRand. How do I ensure that this page can only be accessed from my iPhone app and not from other clients? I've thought of doing some simple password mechanism but that can easily be sniffed by capturing what my app sends out.

The reason for this is to lower the load of my server by only allowing legitimate requests.

Answer (score 11):

You can't really do this. Your application can be disassembled and whatever secret is in the binary can be replicated in a malicious application.

Another attack you should be aware of is people settings the hosts file to a location they control and then installing a root certificate that allows them to provide a signature for that domain. Your application would do the post with the secret, and they'd just be able to read out the secret. They could extract the password from any complicated encryption system within the binary in this way.

Most of the ideas in this thread are vulnerable to this attack.

That said, the likelihood of somebody caring enough to disassemble your application is probably fairly remote.

I'd just keep it simple. Have a password that's hardcoded in to your application. To prevent someone just looking at the resources and trying every string, make it the XOR of two strings or the result of an AES decrypt of a particular fixed string.

Obviously, you should do the request over SSL otherwise an attacker can just sniff the traffic.

Yes, a determined attacker will circumvent the scheme but like any DRM scheme, that's always been the case. The trick is to make it too much effort to be worth it.

Comment: Agreed. Like all security, the trick is to make the cost benefit of accessing the service poor.

Answer (score 2):

To follow up on Simon's idea, you could very easily have a key string in your application, then send the device ID, and then the DeviceID XOR'ed (or some other simple algorithm for string encryption) with your key string.

Since you know the key value to use, it's trivial for you to "decrypt" this string on the sever side and verify that the values match.

This way, the password is different for each user's device, and the "key" string is never sent over the wires of the great unwashed internets. :-)

Yes, this would by no means be impossible to figure out, but like others have said, the idea is not to make it impossible. The idea is to make it more trouble than it is worth.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the https protocol with client-side keys too. You can use one client key for everyone or you can even generate a different key for each client and "register" them at your server.

I suppose that it's a lot of work for small project, but it sounds like the appropriate thing to do if you need authentication.

You should check that keys aren't seen easily by mobile phone owner. And remember that somebody will be able to hack it in any case.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you don't want to use SSL?  If you do then you can open HTTPS session and then pass some secret key in the request.

If you don't want SSL your options are limited: to have pseudo security I suggest both authentication and authorization methods and a third to reduce overall traffic:

Authentication: Generator in client application that creates secret keys by combining with a key file.  The keyfile can be updated every so often for greater security: lets say you update the key file once a week.  To re-cap: Generator combines in app secret with out of app key file to generate a 3rd key for transmission used in authentication.  The server would then be able to authenticate.

Authorization: Of course you also want to lock out rogue applications.  Here it would be best to have authorization mechanism with the site.  Don't replace keyfiles for unless the client logs in.  Track key files to users.  etc.

Traffic reduction: 
If you are receiving obscene amount of traffic or if you suspect someone trying to DOS your server, you can also have both the server and clients sync to request/response on a procedurally generated URL that can change often.  It is wasteful to open/close so many HTTPS sessions if someone is just flooding you with requests.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one thought - send up the device ID along with requests from your app.

Monitor the device ID's used - if you see a ton of requests from different IP's near or at the same time, that device is probably being used as a fixed key in the requests sent to you - block it.

For those that actually send the real device ID from other apps (not yours), you can monitor usage trends to see if the calls match the pattern of how your app performs - like one call being used by a device before some initialization call you would normally expect, and so on - block those too.

Basically by being able to shift rules around patterns of use, you can better adjust to someone trying to use your service by making sure it's not a fixed target like some random use key would be.

You may also want to use a simple use key as well as a first line of defense, and then layer on the traffic analysis approach.  Also custom http header values you look for are another simple way to trip up a naive attacker.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what web technology you are using, but if you are using Ruby on Rails, it uses a secret authentication token in all of its controllers to make sure malicious code isn't accessing destructive methods (via PUSH, POST, or DELETE). You would need to send that authentication token to the server in your request body to allow it to execute. That should achieve what I think you are looking for.

If you're not using Ruby on Rails, that method of code authentication might be a good one to research and implement yourself in whatever technology you are using.

Take a look at the [Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html), specifically section 3.1 (CSRF Countermeasures).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like encrypting the current time and IP address from the iPhone, and then decrypt it on the server. The downside is that you need the iPhone app to know the "secret" key so that only it can generate valid access tokens... and once the key is in the wild, it will only be a matter of time before it's hacked if your app is really worth the effort.

You could encrypt the response using some random portion of the application which is meant to be using it, specifying the location of the binary in an unencrypted bit of the response. Then at least only clients with access to your binary would be able to decrypt it... but again, that's hardly 100% secure.

Ultimately you need to ask yourself how much effort you want to put into securing the service vs how much effort you think hackers will put into abusing it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Cocoa Touch developer, but I think HTTP Authentication over SSL would be easy to implement and it's probably exactly what you're looking for.

All you need to do is setup HTTP Authentication on the server side (you haven't mentioned what you're using on the server side) and create a self-signed SSL cert on your webserver. Done. :)

Tell us more about your setup and we will be able to help you further.

Comment: How does that stop another application using HTTPS from accessing the service? Yes, the hacker would need to find out the authentication details being used, but if we assume a resourceful hacker, I don't think this will stop them.

Comment: As you asked yourself: The question is how much effort he wants to put into securing the service. Sure, a resourceful hacker could use a MITM attack to fetch username/password from the SSL-encrypted traffic, but I think this is a good balance between benefit and cost.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the answers have stated, closing your web service off to everyone else will be a major hassle. The best you can hope for is to make it easier for the hackers to use another web service, than to use yours...

Another suggestion to do this, is to generate random numbers from a [random seed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) on both the server and the client. The server would need to track where in the sequence of random numbers all of the clients are, and match that number to the one sent by the client.

The client would also have to register to be given access to the server. This would also serve as a authentication mechanism.

So:

```
//Client code:
$sequence = file_get_contents('sequence.txt');
$seed = file_get_contents('seed.txt');
$sequence++;

//Generate the $sequence-th random number
srand($seed);
for ($i = 0; $i <= $sequence; $i++) {
    $num = rand();
}
//custom fetch function
get_info($main_url . '?num=' . $num . '&id' = $my_id);
```

This will generate a request similiar to this:

`http://webservice.com/get_info.php?num=3489347&id=3`

```
//Server Code: (I'm used to PHP)

//Get the ID and the random number
$id = (int)$_REQUEST['id'];
$rand = (int)$_REQUEST['num'];
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT `sequence`, `seed` FROM `client_list` WHERE `id` = :id');
if ($stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id)) {
    list($sequence, $seed) = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
$sequence++;

//Generate the $sequence-th random number
srand($seed);
for ($i = 0; $i <= $sequence; $i++) {
    $num = rand();
}
if ($num == $rand) {
    //Allow Access
} else {
    //Deny Access
}
```

By using a a different seed for each client, you ensure that hackers can't *predict* a random number by tracking previous numbers used.