# can hard coded strings in a compiled exe be changed?

Tags: vb.net

Lets say you have some code in your app with a hard coded string.

```
If somevalue = "test123" Then

End If
```

Once the application is compiled, is it possible for someone to modify the .exe file and change 'test123' to something else? If so, would it only work if the string contained the same number of characters?

Comment: What case have you come across and asking sth like that?

Comment: It can and has been done. I sell a small program through the internet. The only version I ever created has hard coded English texts. This is probably a problem for Chinese users because after a few years I discovered a Chinese version of my program on the internet. As they only have access to the executable the must have changed the texts in the .EXE-file

Comment: Just decompile the program with ildasm.exe, modify the string, put it back together with ilasm.exe.  Takes less than a minute.

Comment: it's easy to modify .net assemblies. however, it can be made harder using obfuscation, string encryption, and to a Jesse extent conversion to a native image with ngen. Code signing doesn't stop people changing the strings but does at least stop people modifying your application and issuing it off as the original. ultimately if someone is determined, you can't stop them modifying your assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but not necessarily straightforward. For example, if your string is loaded in memory, someone could use a memory manager tool to modify the value of the string's address directly.

Alternatively, they could decompile your app, change the string, and recompile it to create a new assembly with the new string. However, whether this is likely to happen depends on your app and how important it is for that string to be changed.

You could use an obfuscator to make it a bit harder to do but, ultimately, a determined cracker would be able to do it. The question is whether that string is important enough to worry about and, if so, maybe consider an alternative approach such as using a web service to provide the string.

Comment: The reason i am interested is because i connect to a secure web service and i want to make sure that the certificate being used is the one the application expects (and not the fiddler root certificate for example). I have hard coded strings to check the certificate id in CheckValidationResult, what should i be doing instead?

Comment: Part of HTTPS (I assume you're using HTTPS, otherwise you should be) is to ensure the certificate it from the site that owns it. Anyone who can modify your string could modify your `CheckValidationResult` to return true all the time.

Comment: I am using https. So how am i supposed to handle this? How are you supposed to stop people calling your webservice functions outside of the application?

Comment: Not very easily. The problem is that any security measures you have on the client side can eventually be viewed and spoofed by someone. For example, if you have a secret key you send to your web service (with HTTPS so it's encrypted), someone could still decompile your app and see how that key is being generated.

Comment: Just found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/848830/187697) which sums it up nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Strings hard-coded without any obfuscation techniques can easily be found inside compiled executables by openign them up in any HEX-editor. Once found, replacing the string is possible in 2 ways :

#### 1. Easy way (*conditions apply)

If the following conditions apply in your case, this is a very quick-fire way of modifying the hard-coded strings in the executable binary.

- `length(new-string) <= length(old-string)`
- No logic in the code to check for executable modification using CRC.

This is a viable option ONLY if the new string is equal or shorter than the old string. Use a hex-editor to find occurrences of the old string and replace it with the new string. Pad an extra space with `NULL` i.e. `0x00`

For example `old-long-string` in the binary
[image: old long string in a hex-editor]

is modified to a shorter `new-string` and padded with null characters to the same length as the original string in the binary executable file
[image]

Note that such modifications to the executable files are detected by any code that verifies the checksum of the binary file against the pre-calculate checksum of the original binary executable file.

#### 2. Harder way (applicable in almost all cases)

De-compiling the binary to native code opens up the possibility to modify any strings (and even code) and rebuild it to obtain the new binary executable.

There exist dozens of such de-compiler tools to decompile **`vb.net`** (Visual Studio.net, in general). An excellent detailed comparison of the most popular ones (ILspy, JustDecompile, DotPeek, .NET Reflector to name a few ) can be found **[here](http://blog.filipekberg.se/2013/02/14/decompiling-dotnet-applications/)**.

There do exist scenarios in which even the harder way will NOT be successful. This is the case when the original developer has used obfuscation techniques to prevent the strings from being detected and modified in the executable binary. One such obfuscation technique is **[storing encrypted strings](http://jasonhaley.com/blog/post/2006/06/16/Obfuscation-String-Encryption-.aspx)**.